# How to bypass "Compatibility Checker" dialog?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with many sub-folders and inside of them more then 1000 Excel files.

There are two problems with the following code.

1. This will require me to click continue for each Excel file that needs compatibility
   [image]
2. I need to apply that macro inside those files.
   I mean that I want that macro to be available after the code runs on the files  for reuse in other computer after sending those excel files to other computer

```vb
Sub ProcessFiles()

   Dim objFolder As Object
   Dim objFile As Object
   Dim objFSO As Object
   Dim MyPath As String
   Dim myExtension As String        
   Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

   Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

   With FldrPicker
       .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo EmptyEnd
       MyPath = .SelectedItems(1)
   End With

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Call GetAllFiles(MyPath, objFSO)
   Call GetAllFolders(MyPath, objFSO)
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   MsgBox "Complete."

   EmptyEnd:

End Sub


Sub GetAllFiles(ByVal strPath As String, ByRef objFSO As Object)

   Dim objFolder As Object
   Dim objFile As Object

   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
   For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
       DoWork objFile.Path
   Next objFile

End Sub


Sub GetAllFolders(ByVal strFolder As String, ByRef objFSO As Object)

   Dim objFolder As Object
   Dim objSubFolder As Object

   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
   For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
       Call GetAllFiles(objSubFolder.Path, objFSO)
       Call GetAllFolders(objSubFolder.Path, objFSO)
   Next objSubFolder

End Sub


Sub DoWork(strFile As String)

   Dim wb As Workbook

   If Right(strFile, 4) = "xlsx" Then
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFile)
       With wb
            'Do your work here
             ......
            .Close True
       End With
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Comment: @ShaiRado thanks! that should solved my first problem. where in code it need to be? befre that line:"Application.ScreenUpdating = False"?

Comment: yes, and restore it back to `True` after you restore `ScreenUpdating` to `True` as well

Comment: @ShaiRado, I didn't get it , why should i restore it(Application.ScreenUpdating and Application.DisplayAlerts = False ) back to true?

Comment: you already did restore `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` (look at your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the minor modifications in the code below (instead of your `Sub ProcessFiles` code)

```
Sub ProcessFiles()

   Dim objFolder As Object
   Dim objFile As Object
   Dim objFSO As Object
   Dim MyPath As String
   Dim myExtension As String
   Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

   Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

   With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub ' < can use Exit Sub instead of GoTo
        MyPath = .SelectedItems(1)
   End With

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' <-- add this line
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Call GetAllFiles(MyPath, objFSO)
   Call GetAllFolders(MyPath, objFSO)

   ' restore default settings
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   MsgBox "Complete."

End Sub
```

Comment: in case you want to leave Excel session open later, work with it and get alerts >> then yes